# json parse error unexpected eof turkish character

Tags: php, sql, json

I am pulling data from the database with the sql command. But I take trouble when shooting Turkish characters. For example, I have this problem when there are characters like "ü, ç, ğ, ş". How can I retrieve Turkish characters from the database without problems? I'm running this sql command in the React native.

```
<?php
....
$sql = "SELECT ADET FROM ....TBL_STT_SIPARISLER";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {


 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem);


 }

} else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}
 echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON must be encoded in UTF-8.

You can set the charset of your connection with the function [$conn->set_charset('utf8')](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Comment: It worked, but for example "ü" appears as "\ u00fc". What is the problem?

Comment: You can try `json_encode($tem, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE )`. From https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE  : Encode multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX). Available as of PHP 5.4.0.